# Conditions under which a series converges to another.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In a proof I'm reading they seem to be using a claim like this:

Let $(a_{s,n})_{s,n}$ and $(b_n)_n$ be sequences of real numbers. Suppose $\sum_n b_n$ converges and $\sum_n a_{s,n}$ converges for each fixed $s$. Suppose further that for fixed $n$ we have $a_{s,n} \rightarrow b_n$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$. Then we may conclude that
$$\sum_n |a_{s,n}-b_n| \rightarrow 0$$as $s \rightarrow \infty$.

In particular $$\Big|\sum_n a_{s,n} - \sum_n b_n \Big| \rightarrow 0$$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$,

Is it true? How can I prove it?

Comment: It is better to write "the series $\sum_n b_n$ converge"s rather than "$\sum_n b_n <\infty$" because $\sum_n (-n) = -\infty <\infty$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Right, thank you! I was going to apply the claim to positive numbers so they were positive in my head. Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $b_n$ a summable sequence and define $a_{s,n}= b_n$ for $s\neq n$ and $a_{n,n}=b_n+1$.
Then $\sum_na_{s,n}$ is convergent and $a_{s,n}\to b_n$ as $s\to \infty$. But, for any $s$,
$$\sum_n |a_{s,n}-b_n|=\sum_n a_{s,n}-b_n= \sum_n a_{s,n}-\sum_nb_n= \left|\sum_n a_{s,n}-\sum_nb_n\right| = 1$$